# Получить ссылки к картинкам материалов

Tags: joomla

Есть сайт на Joomla. Для создания страниц и статей используется компонент K2. Код, приведенный ниже выдает мне материалы из категории с id=76 в формате JSON. Но в получаемом файле нет ссылок на изображения материалов. Как можно видоизменить данный код, чтобы в итоговом JSON наряду с другими данными были и ссылки к картинкам?

```
<?php 
$my_path = dirname(__FILE__);
$absolute_path = dirname( $my_path."configuration.php" );
define( '_JEXEC', 1 );
define( 'JPATH_BASE', $absolute_path );
define( 'DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR );

require_once ( JPATH_BASE . DS . 'includes' . DS . 'defines.php' );
require_once ( JPATH_BASE . DS . 'includes' . DS . 'framework.php' );

$mainframe = & JFactory::getApplication( 'site' );
?>


<?php

$host = 'localhost';
$db   = 'dbname';
$user = 'dbuser';
$pass = 'dbpass';
$charset = 'utf8';

$dsn = "mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db;charset=$charset";
$opt = [
PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false,
];

$pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass, $opt);

$response = array();

$result = $pdo->query("SELECT c068t_k2_items.*, c068t_k2_categories.name as catname from c068t_k2_items join c068t_k2_categories on c068t_k2_items.catid = c068t_k2_categories.id where c068t_k2_items.catid in (76)");
$response["items"] = array();
while ($row = $result->fetch()) {
    //print_r($response);
$item = array();
    $item["id"] = $row["id"];
    $item["image"] = JURI::root().'media/k2/items/cache/'.md5("Image".$item["id"]).'_L.jpg';
    $item["title"] = $row["title"];
    $item["catid"] = $row["catid"];
    $item["created"] = $row["created"];
    $item["introtext"] = $row["introtext"];
    $item["catname"] = $row["catname"];
    array_push($response["items"], $item);
}
//$response["success"] = 1;
echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Для получения изображений  K2 item, есть более оптимальный метод.
При загрузке изображений, система создаёт файл и генерирует новое имя для файла методом `md5()` + префикс `Image`, для получения файла:

```
$item->image = JURI::root().'media/k2/items/cache/'.md5("Image".$item->id).'_L.jpg';
```

где `$item->id` - это `id` данного контента.

> UPD

```
 $item["image"] = JURI::root().'media/k2/items/cache/'.md5("Image".$item["id"]).'_L.jpg';
```

> UPD 2

Для подключения класов `Joomla framework`

```
$my_path = dirname(__FILE__);
$absolute_path = dirname( $my_path."/../../configuration.php" );
define( '_JEXEC', 1 );
define( 'JPATH_BASE', $absolute_path );
define( 'DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR );

require_once ( JPATH_BASE . DS . 'includes' . DS . 'defines.php' );
require_once ( JPATH_BASE . DS . 'includes' . DS . 'framework.php' );

$mainframe = & JFactory::getApplication( 'site' );
```

где `dirname( $my_path."/../../configuration.php" );` путь к файлу `configuration.php`

Comment: Это я знаю.. Но в моем файле как мне это сделать? Если я напишу $item->image = JURI::root().'media/k2/items/cache/'.md5("Image".$item->id).'_L.jpg'; мой файл ничего не поймет про этот item.

Comment: почему не поймёт ? в вашем файле есть же переменная $item["id"] ?

Comment: Обекты $item->image и $item->id   я написал как пример

Comment: есть. Можете в вашем ответе дописать кусок кода, который будет делать то что мне нужно? Я написал так  $itm->image = JURI::root().'media/k2/items/cache/'.md5("Image".$itm->id).'_L.jpg';
 $item["image"] = $row[$itm]; и теперь вообще не отображает ничего

Comment: Добавил новый пример, вот так должно у вас быть

Comment: Так написал. Все равно ничего не отображает. Видимо мой файл не знает про JURI::root(). В коде, который я привел в вопросе больше ничего нет. Может его нужно как-то связать с компонентом K2 или joomla, чтобы файл знал откуда брать ему данные?

Comment: Как ? вы пишите код вне Joomla framework ? понятно что у вас будет ошибка 500

Comment: Да, да я пишу вне. Отдельный файл php где я запросом вытаскиваю данные с БД и загоняю их в JSON. Как мне данный файл связать с Joomla framework?

Comment: Добавил в ответ как подгрузить классы

Comment: У меня файл configuration.php в корне и php файл с моим кодом тоже в корне. В свой файл добавил php код, который вы дали но все равно не выполняется. Ничего не выдает. В вопрос добавил весь код, который сейчас получился